# Incorrect Result Order with PHP Heaps

Tags: php, heap

I'm running in to an issue where none of the PHP heap classes store the data in the correct order.

Examples given are trivial, but the error with this small dataset makes a project I'm working on fail spectacularly.

Simple Example:

```
$values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$min = new SplMinHeap();
$max = new SplMaxHeap();
foreach($values as $value){
  $min->insert($value);
  $max->insert($value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($min);
print_r($max);
echo "</pre>";
```

Expected Output:

```
SplMinHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
        )

)
SplMaxHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 1
        )

)
```

Actual Output:

```
SplMinHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
        )

)
SplMaxHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 4
        )

)
```

You can change the order of the initial values array to [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and max heap shows correctly, but min heap is out of order. Both are out of order if the values are randomized
[1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5] shows

```
SplMinHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 6
        )

)
SplMaxHeap Object
(
    [flags:SplHeap:private] => 0
    [isCorrupted:SplHeap:private] => 
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 5
        )

)
```

I've tried the exact code with different $values arrays on https://onlinephp.io/ against different PHP versions, and each one I've tested returns the results the same way, so I have to be misunderstanding the functionality of the heaps (and SplPriorityQueue as it uses max heap but also stores the additional data to process like a queue.

Comment: Don't look at the dump, call `$max->extract();` in a loop and they'll be in the correct order.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't prepared to remove items from the queue while I was coding trying to determine if the items were sorting correctly. Doing the  `->extract()` does pop them in the correct order. Weird that the dump doesn't just show the right order. Now I'm curious how PHP tracks and pops the correct item since it isn't in the order shown in the dump.

Comment: It's open source, you can find the source code and see how it does it.

Comment: I'm aware. Don't have the time to dive into that right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Private means, you should not see it. Use the public supported methods.

Comment: Heaps are not for sequential and ordered data, they are binary tree structures that give fast lookups (i.e. fast access), sorting and ordering has nothing to do with natural sorting. Extraction is the operation of "heapifying", which removes and returns the Root-node from the Heap, and reorders the Heap with a new Root node. Min and Max Heaps aren't used to sort the data, they merely give you the maximum value in O(1) time (because the root will always be the largest number and the opposite for minimums. Using PHP Heaps to HeapSort requires extra code and is less efficient on an array.

Comment: "none of the PHP heap classes store the data in the correct order" -- because the correct order in a Heap does not mean sorted order, it's the correct order for super fast inserts, extracts and lookups. A super useful write up here: https://doeken.org/blog/heaps-explained-in-php. If you want sorting just sort the array using `sort` which uses a quicksort algorithm and is ~4x faster than a heapsort algorithm. And SplPriorityQueues are just fast FIFOs, nothing is sorted natually in them either.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that the array representation of a heap must be *sorted*. This is not true. A heap only guarantees order between child and parent. In a min-heap a child's value is never less than its parent's value, and in a max-heap it is never greater. See also the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

Let's look at the last of your examples where you claim they are "out of order":

```
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 6
        )
```

This array is the representation of this binary tree:

```
        1
      /   \
     3     2
    / \   / \
   5   8 7   4
  / \
 9   6
```

As we can see, the min-heap property is nowhere violated: every child node has a value that is not less than its parent has. So it is a valid min-heap.

And the max heap:

```
    [heap:SplHeap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 5
        )
```

This array represents this binary tree:

```
        9
      /   \
     8     7
    / \   / \
   6   3 2   4
  / \
 1   5
```

Also here we can see that the max-heap property is nowhere violated: every child node has a value that is not greater than its parent has. So it is a valid max-heap.